# Is '[]' a valid regular expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
[ [ 'or', [ 'ar', 1, undef, ['v'] ], ['v'] ] ]
```

What does this mean? Either in Perl or Perl regular expression? What does it try to pass? Is this valid? I thought `[]` can only be characters in them for a regular expression.

Comment: context would be nice rather than a random set of characters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with regular expressions in this context. It creates an arrayref that contains other arrayrefs--in other words, a complex datastructure. You could store this in a scalar:

```
my $foo = [ [ 'or', [ 'ar', 1, undef, ['v'] ], ['v'] ] ];
```

And print some things out:

```
say $$foo[0][0];       # "or"
say $$foo[0][1][0];    # "ar"
say $$foo[0][1][3][0]; # "v"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an array reference. Have a read of *[perlreftut - Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)*.

Comment: No,OP is asking about perl regexes. The `[]` is this case would be `character classes`. Although it's a bit unclear, given the example.

Comment: @chrsblck -- I don't think he is actually asking about regexen, because that code snippet doesn't make much sense as a character class. It does make sense as a complex datastructure, but he probably hasn't encountered one before and got confused about seeing the syntax outside of a regex.

Comment: @frezik - agreed, at least that's how I interpreted the question

Comment: @tjmw true, the example doesn't match the question.

Comment: @frezik is right. It is an array reference. But it was used to check file name as well. I was not sure what to make out of it. Thanks.